# How to return all columns but GROUP BY a subset of those columns using a COUNT aggregate with Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm trying to return all columns from a table in ClickHouse, however I would like to count the number of `students` in `Program` as a field. Ideally the query would return `University, Student, Program, student_count`. The count would be how many 'Programs' there are grouped by `University`. An example query is below

```
SELECT 
    University,
    Program, 
    Student,
    COUNT(Program) as student_count
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    University
```

Example Data:

```
| University  | Student   | Program   |
| ----------- | --------- | --------- |
| University A| Student 1 | Program A |
| University A| Student 2 | Program A |
| University A| Student 3 | Program B |
| University B| Student 4 | Program A |
| University B| Student 5 | Program B |
```

Desired Data:

```
| University  | Student  |Program   |student_count|
| ----------- | ---------| -------- | ----------- | 
| University A| Student 1| Program A|2            |
| University A| Student 2| Program A|2            |
| University A| Student 3| Program B|1            |
| University B| Student 4| Program A|1            |
| University B| Student 5| Program B|1            |
```

My question is is this even possible with ClickHouse, and if so how would it be implemented?

Comment: @jarlh Just updated it, I hope that clarifies everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clickhouse does support standard [window functions](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions), therefore:

```sql
SELECT 
    University,
    Program, 
    Student,
    count(*) over (partition by University, Program) as student_count
FROM 
    table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        t1.University,
        t1.Student,
        t1.Program,
        t2.student_count
    FROM 
        table AS t1
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            University,
            Program,
            COUNT(DISTINCT Student) AS student_count
        FROM 
            table
        GROUP BY 
            University, Program
    ) AS t2 ON t1.University = t2.University AND t1.Program = t2.Program
```